# Aliens save two humans from an Earth about to end, both girls

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, aliens, post-apocalyptic

What's the name of the book/short-story sci-fi anthology that contains this story about aliens saving two high school humans just before an Earth-destroying event (possibly nuclear war or some other catastrophe)? The aliens are trying to preserve the human species by getting one of both sexes but they chose based on clothing (because they don't understand enough about human gender) and both humans turn out to be girls.

Comment: Are you the same person who wrote the last post [here](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1565363-scifi-short-aliens-save-two-humans-from-an-earth-about-to-be-destroyed#comment_form)?

Comment: @Adamant I think so, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: @NVZ - If they are different people, and this gets answered, I would want to make sure that other person gets notified. If they are the same, I needn't bother.

Comment: @Adamant aha, that's very kind of you to do. :)

Comment: I am the same woman (Marsha) from Goodreads.com. I thought I'd post the question here and help out Justanotherbiblophile by addressing the question to people more qualified to answer than general readers.

Answer (score 5):

It might be Roger Zelazny's short story *Fire and/or Ice*. It starts with –"Mommy! Mommy!" –"Yes?" –"Yes?" –"Tell me again what you did in the war." The premise is that Götterdämmerung brings the end of the world, and a being that calls itself Loki saves two human survivors, but doesn't realize that both are girls because one is dressed as a man. It turns out that both are pregnant. "And we both had twins, and lived happily ever after."

The story is the first of the triplet *Fire and/or Ice, Exeunt Omnes, A Very Good Year*, originally for Robert Sheckley's anthology [*After the Fall*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1719) (1980), and republished in Zelazny's [*Unicorn Variations*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?52816) (1983).